# while loop in c goes on indefinitely

Tags: c, while-loop

When I compile and run this code, the while loop does not stop. Where did I go wrong?

```
/*Program to find all armstrong numbers between 1 and 500*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,rem_t,rem_h,dig_u,dig_t,dig_h;
i=1;
    while(i<=500)
    {
    rem_t=i%100;
    rem_h=i%1000;
    dig_u=i%10;
    dig_t=(rem_t-dig_u)/10;
    dig_h=(rem_h-rem_t)/100;
    if (i=(dig_u*dig_u*dig_u)+(dig_t*dig_t*dig_t)+(dig_h*dig_h*dig_h))
        {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One word - debugger. Actually, your `printf` tells you all you need to know already.

Comment: I don't see `++i` anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

- You used `=` in place of `==` in the `if` statement, and
- You did not increment `i` at the end of loop's body.

The compiler would warn you of the second problem, but the first one "hides" it.

```
if (i==(dig_u*dig_u*dig_u)+(dig_t*dig_t*dig_t)+(dig_h*dig_h*dig_h))
    {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    }
i++;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/eKBzNO)

Comment: What do you mean "hide"?

Comment: The first problem prevents the compiler from detecting the second problem.

Comment: @iamBRJ The compiler sees an assignment, so it decides that it is your intention to assign `i` to `(dig_u*dig_u*dig_u)+(dig_t*dig_t*dig_t)+(dig_h*dig_h*dig_h)` expression at the end of the loop, and combine it with a condition check.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, you must increment i, otherwise, it stays at one, and then i is always less than or equal to 500. So, at the end of the while loop, you must increment i in some way in order for the loop to terminate.

Comment: Well, you must modify i somewhere in the loop such that it eventually becomes > 500. But that does not mean that you must use i++.